# How to make a border half so long?

Tags: html, css, border

I want to make a orange border around an inputfield like in the picture.
The border-bottom is no problem but the left and right border are only 50% high of the full height. How can I make this?

[Here you see what I would like to reach.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3ecp.png)

---

The following code is how I did it. Thanks to @craig

```css
 .input{
 -webkit-border-image:linear-gradient(to top,black, rgb(0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%) 1 50%;
    -moz-border-image:linear-gradient(to top,black, rgb(0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%) 1 50%;
    -o-border-image:linear-gradient(to top,black, rgb(0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%) 1 50%;
    border-image:linear-gradient(to top, black, rgb(0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%) 1 50%;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <input name="email" class="input" type="email" required=""placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Posto your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're after is a color gradient for the left and right side.

Investigate the following link: https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

In the above examples they use 100% - I would try 50%;

```
input {
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f49c30 0%, #f49c30 50%, #f2f2f2 50%, #f2f2f2 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f49c30 0%,#f49c30 50%,#f2f2f2 50%,#f2f2f2 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f49c30 0%,#f49c30 50%,#f2f2f2 50%,#f2f2f2 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
The link you posted helped me!